# Elasticsearch Insert single key if not exists, without affecting other keys

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

In some of my documents, I have a key present as `school`. Say the document is:

```
{
    "id" : "123",
    "name" : "Robert",
    "school" : "Public"
}
```

Now, `school` is not present in all documents. I want to insert `school` key in all documents where it is not already present with a default String.

I am using Elasticsearch version number `2.4.5`. How can I do it? Am I looking at a bulk update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would clearly use the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html) API for this. You can search for all documents that don't have the `school` field and set it to whatever default value you wish:

```
POST your-index/your-type/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "school"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.school = 'dummy'"
  }
}
```

Note that you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) and restart your ES server.

Comment: Thanks Val. I am sure this is what I want. Let me see how I can enable `inline` scripts on my index, as I am facing `script_exception` right now. Please feel free to point me to something for this, but the OP is surely solved and I'll accept the answer once I am successful in updating data.

Comment: Though this solves the issue, what if someone doesn't want to enable the use of scripts on `server`, may it be for any reason? Is there an alternative in using the script?

Comment: Scripts open up some vulnerabilities, but you can customize which scripts you want to allow on your server and also have a host of other possible configurations to secure your ES server.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Still, the same question though, is there an alternative to using the script, maybe using a native ES query?

Comment: You could use Logstash with an `elasticsearch` input to run the same query,  add the `school` field and then an `elasticsearch` output to update the documents.